# PHP Name validation RegEx

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate the user names at register, using the following code:

```
$str = $input['s_name'];
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s.+&-]$/';   
$validname = 0;
$validname = preg_match($pattern, $str);

if ($validname == 0) {
    $flash_error .= _m('The name is not valid') . PHP_EOL;
    $error[] = 10;
}
```

The Regex should allow only names that start with a letter or number and contain only the following characters: **white space** **.** **+** **&** **-**

This should allow users to enter normal names (**John Doe**) and company names like **T&T Production 007 B.V.A.**

The problem is that every regex form I try, returns the error *The name is not valid*, for the above example: *T&T Production 007 B.V.A.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s.+&-]+$` note: a **+** sign added in end of pattern.

Comment: Tried it before, even with ```/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s.+&-]*$/``` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine, see php [demo](https://ideone.com/xgiDaX) (maybe checking value of $input['s_name'] helps you)

Comment: Found the problem. It's the & character that gets somehow trimmed and the form returns https://i.ibb.co/DV4P0NV/fail.png 

So how to deal with ```&amp;``` and add it in the Regex ?

Comment: To be fair the entire premise of "valid" names is flawed, but if you consider your aporoach your real problem is that both `.` __DOT ALL__ and `+` have speacial meaning in regex and should be eacaped to have literal meaning. Otherwise consider the problem posed by names like __O'Riley__ or names without latin Alphabet characters like  __Schlüter__ which will fail your regex check. You could resolve this problem with a PCRE Unicode Code Character property `\p{L}`.

Comment: @Sherif `.` and `+` loose their special meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s.+&amp;-]+$/'
```

Thanks **Alireza** for the help!